# Как наладить соединение между сервером и клиентами? c++

Tags: c++, qt

Есть сервер с базой данных пользователей, комнатами(чатами для пользователей), в которые можно попасть только зная пароль.
Так вот, как реализовать соединение между пользователем и сервером?
UDP соединение для отправки сообщений, TCP для обмена логином/паролями.
(Использую QT)

Comment: Если вы работаете с базой данных, то вам недостаточно будет использования TCP и и UDP. Вам нужно будет использовать драйвер базы данных. В Qt есть драйвера для mysql, MsSqlServer, PostgreSQL и др. Для доступа к ним используется класс [QSqlDatabase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html)

Comment: База данных уже есть.

Comment: Я не спорю, что она у вас есть. Я говорю о том, что средствами чистых TCP и UDP вам к ней не подключиться. Для более предметного разговора укажите СУБД.

Comment: Я написал свою.

Comment: @Alleksh_, ваш вопрос немного беспредметен. Добавьте кода или подробнее расскажите, что у вас клиент, что у вас сервер. В общем случае на сервере всегда открыт слушающий сокет (у вас будет два: тср и удп). Клиент сначала подключается к ТСР, авторизуется, получает некий токен авторизации, с которым он уже может слать запросы в удп сокет. Средствами QT это реализуемо классами QTcpServer и QTcpSocket (там же есть примеры клиент-серверных приложений)